# AngularDart how to add and remove css class on click

Tags: html, css, dart, onclick, angular-dart

I am trying to add and remove css class in AngularDart by click event.
So far I have successfully perform adding class to selected html element, however I cannot figure out how to remove this class. It seems that the function does not see the change in the value of the "openMenu" variable.

HTML code:

```
<header id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="assets/svg/Logo.svg" alt="Logo SEC">
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">What we offer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work with us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span (click)="clickBurger()" class="nav-burger"></span>
    </label>
</header>
```

DART code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  styleUrls: ['nav_bar_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'nav_bar_component.html',
  directives: [coreDirectives, MaterialIconComponent, NavBarComponent
  ],
)
class NavBarComponent {
      Element menuBtn;
      bool openMenu;
  
  void clickBurger() {
      final menuBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-burger');
      openMenu = false;

      if(openMenu == false){
        menuBtn.classes.add('open');
        openMenu = true;
      } else if (openMenu == true){
        menuBtn.classes.remove('open');
        openMenu = false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You are initializing `openMenu` to false at the beginning of your function, therefore it will always add the class

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `openMenu` to false every time `clickBurger` is called - just before your if block. Instead, set `openMenu` to false when you declare it in your class.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  directives: [coreDirectives, MaterialIconComponent]
)
class AppComponent {
  Element menuBtn;
  bool openMenu = false; // set to false here

  void clickBurger() {
    final menuBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-burger');
    // openMenu = false; // remove this statement

    if (openMenu == false) {
      menuBtn.classes.add('open');
      openMenu = true;
    } else if (openMenu == true) {
      menuBtn.classes.remove('open');
      openMenu = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I'll also mention a couple more things.

Unless you need to keep track of the state of the burger menu for other reasons, you can simplify your code considerably by using `toggle` instead of `add` and `remove`.

Also, you are declaring two different variables for `menuBtn`. One in the class scope and the other in your `clickBurger` function. I don't think you intend to have both, and certainly you don't need both.

After a bit of refactoring, it could look like this

```
// (import statements and component annotation)

class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  void clickBurger() {
    document.querySelector('.nav-burger').classes.toggle('open');
  }
}
```

Going one step further, we can break out the `querySelector` call to happen only once and store it in a member variable. We will need to use `OnInit` though to ensure the component has loaded before we search the DOM for the `.nav-burger` element.

```
// (import statements and component annotation)

class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  Element menuBtn;

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    menuBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-burger');
  }

  void clickBurger() => menuBtn.classes.toggle('open');
}
```

Lastly, just for reference I will mention an alternative way to achieve this behavior is through class binding in your template. You might prefer to do it like we have done above above, or you may prefer class binding instead. You can read more about class binding in the docs: https://angulardart.dev/guide/template-syntax#class-binding